# error: could not find function "flush.console"

Tags: r

If I run my R script via `.Rprofile` > `source("C:/..../Rscript.R)`, (runs the R script immediately upon starting RStudio),  I get this strange error: `could not find function "flush.console"`.

If I run the block straight after the error by hand (select the block and run) it works.

This R script (with the same procedure) works on other desktop PC. (except not all libraries are loaded, but these are not related to the R script I'm trying to execute.)

Where the error could be?

I'm using latest version of `R` and `RStudio`. Again, this all works on other PC. One would suggest that this is PC related, but I don't see how. (same system, `Windows 7`)

I read on SO something about `Sys.sleep()` but I removed that bit and still getting the `error`.

I'm probably not really precise as well as not providing detailed information (along with the R script), but would disclose more information upon request if needed.

Comment: Is the utils package loaded when you call `flush.console`? Try using `utils::flush.console`

Comment: uff, I just included two libraries: `MASS` and `lubridate` and it works now.

Comment: @Roland: yes indeed, the `utils` package is loaded along with MASS library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `help("Startup")`:

> Note that when the site and user profile files are sourced only the
>   base package is loaded, so objects in other packages need to be
>   referred to by e.g. utils::dump.frames or after explicitly loading the
>   package concerned.